# PDO Read From Database

Tags: php, pdo

I have made a code using PDO to read a table from a database.
I try to echo my result but I get a blank page without error.

My Code Is:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
id = "264540733647332";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydata", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='".$id."';"); 

    if ($result->fetchColumn() != 0)
    {
        foreach ( $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) as $row ) {

            $Data1 = $row['Data1'];
            $Data2 = $row['Data2'];

           echo $Data2;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But the echo is empty without any error.
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you All!

Comment: Try this:- `$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='".$id."'"); `

Comment: Hello, I made the change but without result and no error. Still I can't see the echo. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: `$result` is probably failing. Echo the query and see if it works when executed directly. Also you should use prepared statements. I presume `$id` is coming from the client?

Comment: ...or rather is this a typo here or in your code? `id = "264540733647332";` id is not preceded by `$`? Also if `id` is set as an `int` in your DB `264540733647332` is too large.

Comment: This is a typo here, not in my code. Sorry about that! The id is an example for here! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to change:

- dont forget `$`
- if your going to catch the error, catch the whole pdo code
- You can use `rowCount()` to count the rows
- echo something if the record count is 0

```
include 'config.php';
$id = "264540733647332";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydata", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='".$id."';"); 

    if ($result->rowCount() != 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        echo $row['Data1'];
        echo $row['Data2'];
    }else{
        echo 'no row found';
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "error  " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also use prepared statements for example:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=:id"); 
$result->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
```

Comment: This missing $ is a typo here, not in my code. Sorry about that! Thank you so much for your solution. The code is working now!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's only one record with the id "264540733647332".

The issue is that `$result->fetchColumn()` call reads first row in the result set and then advances to the next result. Since there's only one of the results, the subsequent call to  `$result->fetchAll()` returns nothing, hence no data displayed.

To fix this replace `fetchColumn` with `rowCount`:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
id = "264540733647332";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydata", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='".$id."';"); 

    if ($result->fetchColumn() != 0)
    {
        foreach ( $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) as $row ) {

            $Data1 = $row['Data1'];
            $Data2 = $row['Data2'];

           echo $Data2;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I change the fetchColumn with rowCount and the code is working now!